# SQL SERVER 2008- Unable to get the object definition for few objects in ddl schema?

Tags: java, sql-server, encryption, schema, ddl

I am using `MS SQL SERVER 2008` database in which i create `all objects` like `procedure`,`functions`,`views` etc. Now create a sample program get all objects `definition(ddl)`, Here i found that some of `objects definition` is **null** i used following `sql query` to `get definition` of all procedures:

> **Select object_definition(object_id) from sys.objects where type = 'P'**

Here are my sample code:

```
public class sam {
    String userName;
    String dbURL;
    String password;

    public sam(String dbURL, String userName, String password) {
        this.dbURL = dbURL;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void createSQLFile() throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, userName, password);
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        String queryString = "Select object_definition(object_id) from sys.objects where type = 'P'";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
    }
```

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

```
    String dbURl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=db";
    String userName = "u";
    String password = "P";
    new sam(dbURl, userName, password).createSQLFile();

}
```

}                                                                             Also i have attach a screen shots of my database where procedure listed **(Note: The highlighted procedure deification are null)**.
 [image]

**Can anyone suggest- How to get these object defination as they are encrypted?**

Comment: ["A user can only view the metadata of securables that the user owns or on which the user has been granted permission. This means that metadata-emitting, built-in functions such as OBJECT_DEFINITION may return NULL if the user does not have any permission on the object."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090.aspx)

Comment: Maybe also read this: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2964/encrypting-and-decrypting-sql-server-stored-procedures-views-and-userdefined-functions/

Comment: Thank you for reply. In this link for encrypted objects it require a DAC(dedicated administrator connection). How can i apply DAC in my sample code so i can connect using DAC and What will be the URL format for using DAC in java code?

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090.aspx) states

> The definition of user objects is visible to the object owner or grantees that have any one of the following permissions:
>    ALTER,
>    CONTROL,
>    TAKE OWNERSHIP,
>    or VIEW DEFINITION.